# Cast Meteor.js DDP date to Java Date

Tags: java, android, json, date, ddp

I am using [Android DDP Client](https://github.com/kenyee/android-ddp-client) library to connect my Android client to [Meteor-JS](https://www.meteor.com/) server. When I receive a new object I use the following code to parse a "createdAt" field

```
private Map<String, Object> fields;
private Date timestamp;
/*...*/
timestamp = (Date) fields.get("createdAt");
```

I wrongfully assumed that it should be of [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) type. And I get the exception with an error message:

```
com.google.gson.internal.LinkedHashTreeMap cannot be cast to java.util.Date
```

How to parse the Date sent by Meteor correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor-JS sends you a JSON.

```
// The Date value in the JSON response is a Unix timestamp.
// It gives the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.
// So we can do:
Double jsonDate = ((Map<String, Double>) fields.get("createdAt")).get("$date");
timestamp = new Date(jsonDate.longValue());
```

**ps.** I'd recommend to store timestamp as `long` field instead of `Date`.